# How to check eliminate several rows from a dataframe using R

Tags: r, excel, subset

I have two excel files A and B. Excel file A has 6 columns with 10,000 rows. Assume that columns are named A-F. Excel file B has one column (A) with 3500 rows. Here is what I want to do-
I want to eliminate rows based on the cell values (ids) in column A (in excel file A) and have a dataframe without them. To further elaborate- I want to check each id in Column A (excelfile A) against all ids in columnA in  excel file B. If the id in column A in excel file A matches with any of the listed ids in columnA of excel file B, then, I want to eliminate those rows with matching ids in excel file A.

I was able to do this in excel. I want to do the same with R as a crosscheck. I am new to R and I am learning. Could someone help me with a best way to do this?
I know how to subset rows based on header title and a particular value of a cell. But, in this case, I have data with 10,000 observations, of which, I want to eliminate at least 3500 through matching the ids.